# Disable SCSS last-of-type

Tags: typescript, sass

I create a page in typescript. My page has the .html , the .ts and the .scss

So when I run my website and look inside the "inspect page" of google, my table has code  inside : td.mat-cell:last-of-type with padding-right: 24px

I don't have nothing in my .SCSS about this.

So How I can remove this padding right ?
I try

```
td.mat-cell{
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example, you're styling `td.mat-cell {}` but that's less specific than the `td.mat-cell:last-of-type {}` selector.

Try this:

```
td.mat-cell:last-of-type {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Or, if you'd like to format it a bit to leverage SCSS nesting (this is purely a stylistic preference):

```
td.mat-cell {
  &:last-of-type {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly. It works. But the strangest thing is WHY this appear when I don't have nothing about last-of-type in my code ???

Comment: In your browser inspector, see if you can scroll past all of your custom CSS properties and find something from the "user agent stylesheet." Browsers do have defaults that apply to even pages with 0 CSS added. It may be something "default" in your browser – the inspector should indicate those (Chrome shows them in italic text to imply user-agent)